# Missing links on the bottom of questions

Tags: bug, questions, user-interface

When I look at the bottom of a question, I see the following text.

> [image: screenshot]

It seems a problem of CSS styles, since inspecting the HTML shows this.

> [image: screenshot]

I saw this on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135613/access-denied-after-erpal-platform-install), but I get the problem could be present in other sites as well.

If that makes any difference, I see this on OS X Yosemite, using Safari Version 8.0 (10600.1.25).

Comment: No repro on IE11, or FF33, or Chrome38